# Why i see a bar plot with geom_line of ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, lubridate

I have the following `data.frame` where i have multiple variables that I would like to draw using `ggplot`. I understand if using the `Date` without splitting into `Year`, `Month`, and `Day` will get the `line plot` but would like to know, how using the `Year` column can get me the `line plot`?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), to = as.Date("2014-12-31"), by = "day"),
                  F = runif(1461,20,60), D = runif(1461,30,70)) %>% 
                  separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day")) 

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Year))+
  geom_line(aes(y = F)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = D))
```

Comment: I tried `x = as.numeric(Year)` and `as.integer(Year)` while `ggploting` but no success.

Answer (score 2):

Make `Year` numeric, and then choose some kind of summary function for `y` (otherwise you'll get vertical lines that look like bars).

```r
DF %>%
  mutate(across(Year, as.numeric)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year))+
  geom_line(stat = "summary", aes(y = F), fun = mean, color = 'red') +
  geom_line(stat = "summary", aes(y = D), fun = mean, color = 'blue')
```

[image]

Note that you can simplify a bit by pivoting `F` and `D` to their own column:

```r
DF %>%
  mutate(across(Year, as.numeric)) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(F, D)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, color = name))+
  geom_line(stat = "summary", fun = mean)
```

[image]